# Unselect all dates except current month (VBA EXCEL AUTOFILTER)

Tags: vba, excel

[image]I am currently trying to unselect the current month using VBA I know how to select just the current month using VBA (the code is below) but I don't know how to unselect the current month while leaving the other months on.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("d1:d6").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=xlFilterThisMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
```

Comment: But the filter im working on is in column D?

Comment: Is that not how the function works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("d1:d20").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlOr, _
     Criteria1:="<=" & Application.EoMonth(Date, -1), _
     Criteria2:=">" & Application.EoMonth(Date, 0)
```

Note:

- `EoMonth(Date, 0)` marks the last day of current month
- `EoMonth(Date, -1)` marks the last day of previous month

Comment: It just deselects everything

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera not in my tests. There might be something different in your data (and make sure you are setting the field parameter correctly). Is your column `D` formatted as `Date`?

Comment: I added a picture of it above but it is formatted as date

Comment: Yes I did but don't I want to do field 4?

Comment: @AngatvirSanghera I changed the formula to **exclude** the current month instead of showing the current month. p.s. If you use range(d1:d...) then it should be field = 1.

Comment: I appreciate all your help but still removes everything for some reason

Comment: I do understand your logic but it unchecks every box

Comment: Nvm you are right it does it but it just doesn't check and uncheck the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you first try to deselect the filter

```
Cells.AutoFilter
```

Then you select all the other months

Comment: There are not just months there are years also this would be extremely inconvenient

Comment: @A.S.H. -  Can I implement same code for a Quarter?

Comment: Sheets("Sheet1").Range("d1:d20").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlOr, _
     Criteria1:="<=" & Application.EoQuarter(Date, -1), _
     Criteria2:=">" & Application.EoQuarter(Date, 0)